# How to parse an HTML webpage and remove <br> tags?

Tags: html-parsing, simple-html-dom

i need to parse a website that contains `<p>` tags (many of them) i want to get them and put them on a csv file (in same column).

After testing, i'm seeing the paragraphs are not on the same column, it's because of the `<br>` that are on `<p>` tags example :

HTML :

```
<div class="text">
     <p> hello <br> friends </p>
     <p> parsing is cool <br> using <br> simpleHTMLdom </p>
</div>
```

When i parse the html below i get the two `<p>` but not on same csv "column".

My code :

```
if($html_book_page->find('.text')){

   foreach($html_book_page->find('div[class=text] p') as $bookPreview){
      array_push($book, $bookPreview->plaintext);

        }                     
    }
```

$book is the array containing all text and i put $book on csv like :

```
fputcsv($open_csv, array_values($book), ',', ' ');
```

Any way to get :
 (header of csv : TEXT ) and inside :
"Hello friends parsing is cool using simpleHTMLdom" ? Because for moment i have "Hello" and in another column i've "friends" .. "parsing is cool" ..."using".... "simpleHTMLdom"

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do a `jQuery.remove()` before your CSV insert? Something like this:

```
$('.text p').find('br').remove()
```

If you don't want to permanently remove `<br>` from the page, you could do something like this in your for-loop:

```
foreach($html_book_page - > find('div[class=text] p') as $bookPreview) {
  $bookPreview.innerHTML.replace("<br>", "");
  array_push($book, $bookPreview - > plaintext);
}
```